# Can the Web 8.5 Experience Optimization Query service be load balanced?

Tags: experience-optimization, web8.5, load-balancing, scalability

We are designing an infrastructure for SDL Web 8.5 which has Experience Optimisation.

Is there a possibility to scale the Experience Optimization Query microservice into a load balanced environment?

It is not clear from this diagram in the documentation whether that is possible: [Outscaled Experience Optimization environment](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-999209C1-C103-4BA4-871D-4DA579378FCC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. It's like the other microservices. As long as you register the load balancer URL for the capability, it should work just fine.